# how to show a record values in text box in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, webforms

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {        
            binddata();    
        }
        SqlConnection con;
        SqlDataAdapter da;
        DataSet ds;

        void binddata()
        {
            string pid = Request.QueryString["Prod_Id"];
            con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\sqlexpress; initial catalog=PracticeDb; user id=sa; pwd=manager;");
            con.Open();
            da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Products where Prod_Id='" + pid + "'", con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            con.Close();
            listview.DataSource = ds; 
            listview.DataBind(); 
        }
    } 
 }
```

the user is directed to the record updation page  when he click the edit link in the record list page. what should i do write in datasource and databind

Comment: need to show full details of your peoblem and use `Page.ISPostBack` property into your `Page_Load` otherwise it will create a problem for you.

Comment: get the field from `ds` you want to get and pass this thing in `querystring` or use `session` variables and get that value in next page assign it to textbox easily.

Comment: @Rahul well i want to show the record for updation in textbox how can i do this ?

Comment: ok but you want to update the fields in that same page or in different page.

Comment: just for show record in `textbox` use `TextBox1.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["name"].Tostring();` and for furthur detail check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to extract the values from `DataSet` like

```
string name = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["name"].ToString();
```

Here i am assuming that you have a `name` as a field in your select query, you have to use your fields.
After getting that field assign it to `TextBox` like

```
TextBox1.Text = name ;
```

After that run your `update` query based on `Primary Key`.

**One Important Suggestion :-**

Try to use `Page.IsPostBack` property of your Page on `Page_Load`.Need to change your `Page_Load` like

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!Page.IsPostBack)
  {
   binddata();
  }
}
```

Hope you understand and works for you.

Comment: There is an error 'TextBox1.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Prod_Name"].ToString();' cannot find Table 0.

Comment: Rahul the first method worked by storing fields in a variable Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this.

`TextBox1.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["name"].Tostring();`

Comment: thats exactly what im doing.